# minikube and ingress-nginx does not have port 80 open

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes

I'm new to ingress-nginx and I enabled it with minikube using `minikube addons enable ingress`.  When looking for the services related to ingress-nginx, I ran `kubectl get services -n kube-system` and got:

```
NAME                                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP      EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP   10.96.141.138   <none>        443/TCP                  16m
kube-dns                             ClusterIP   10.96.0.10      <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   16m
```

Noticing that I'm missing port 80, I ran `kubectl describe service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission -n kube-system` and got:

```
Name:              ingress-nginx-controller-admission
Namespace:         kube-system
Labels:            addonmanager.kubernetes.io/mode=Reconcile
                   app.kubernetes.io/component=controller
                   app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx
                   app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
Annotations:       <none>
Selector:          app.kubernetes.io/component=controller,app.kubernetes.io/instance=ingress-nginx,app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx
Type:              ClusterIP
IP:                10.96.141.138
Port:              https-webhook  443/TCP
TargetPort:        webhook/TCP
Endpoints:         172.17.0.3:8443
Session Affinity:  None
Events:            <none>
```

When trying to access an endpoint `https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.kube-system.svc.cluster.local/foo`, I get this error:

```
FetchError: request to https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.kube-system.svc.cluster.local/foo failed, reason: unable to verify the first certificate
```

, although hitting the endpoint `/foo` from within a pod through the ingress works just fine.  I was looking into the [tls related documentation](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/tls/) to no avail.  Any help on this would be much appreciated.

EDIT: I've added the output of `kubectl get svc -A` per request:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                                 TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default       auth-svc                             ClusterIP      10.100.218.231   <none>        4000/TCP                     13s
default       client-svc                           ClusterIP      10.106.143.107   <none>        3000/TCP                     12s
default       kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      37m
kube-system   ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.96.141.138    <none>        443/TCP                      36m
kube-system   kube-dns                             ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       37m
```

Comment: Add output of `kubectl get svc -A`

Comment: @ArghyaSadhu thanks. I updated the original post with that information

Comment: Which version of minikube? Which driver for minikube?

Comment: @zigarn I'm using minikube version 1.16.0 on arch linux. I haven't specified the driver, so I believe the default. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

running `kubectl expose deployment ingress-nginx-controller --target-port=80 --type=NodePort -n kube-system` allows me to access the ingress from within a pod in the cluster.

Answer (score 0):

The service you're looking at is, as it's name indicates, the [*Admission Controller*](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2019/03/21/a-guide-to-kubernetes-admission-controllers/) of the minikube ingress addon. 
It's used by the *Ingress Controller* to parse the *Ingress* definitions and configure the underlying nginx (you can take a look at the [minikube ingress addon deployment](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/blob/master/deploy/addons/ingress/ingress-dp.yaml.tmpl))

To access the exposed Ingresses that you may have defined, you need to hit the **ports 80 or 443 of the minikube machine** (available via `minikube ip`). (You can see those listening ports by doing a `minikube ssh -- docker container ls --filter label=app.kubernetes.io/name=ingress-nginx`)

The documentation you need is this one: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/ingress-minikube/

So, if you defined an *Ingress* with `host=hello-world.info` and `path=/foo`, you will be able to access it with:

```sh
curl --header 'Host: hello-world.info' http://`minikube ip`:80/foo
```

Of course, it's better to define a DNS entry to map `hello-world.info` to the minikube IP.

Comment: thanks. I should have clarified that I'm able to hit `hello-world.info` as well as the minikube ip.  I'm just unable to hit that ip from within one of the pods, which I was trying to do when trying to hit `https://ingress-nginx-controller-admission.kube-system.svc.cluster.local/foo`. Hopefully, this helps clarify my goal.  Thanks!

Comment: Ingress are more to serve service to outside of cluster; from inside cluster, just use direct access to service.
The service `ingress-nginx-controller-admission` is not meant to expose the ingress controller, it's for internal mechanisms of ingresses.
If you **need** to go through the ingress, you have to act like from outside: add a DNS entry available from your pods, or create your own service on port 80 of the deployment `ingress-nginx-controller`, **but** then the name of the service and the `host` of the Ingress must match.

Answer (score 0):

Nginx ingress on minikube does not use service to provide access to ingress pods.

It uses hostPort. Here is part of a yaml of ingres controller's pod:

```
$ kubectl get pod -n kube-system   ingress-nginx-controller-789d9c4dc-5wnc2 -oyaml

[...]
ports:
- containerPort: 80
  hostPort: 80
  name: http
  protocol: TCP
- containerPort: 443
  hostPort: 443
  name: https
  protocol: TCP
- containerPort: 8443
  name: webhook
  protocol: TCP
[...]
```

It's behavior is documented in [k8s api reference docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#containerport-v1-core)

> **hostPort**
> Number of port to expose on the host. If specified, this must be a valid port number, 0 < x < 65536. If HostNetwork is specified, this must match ContainerPort. Most containers do not need this.

Thanks to this, ingress can be easly accessed with:

```
curl $(minikube ip)
```