# Kubernetes Ingress not working on Docker for desktop mac

Tags: docker, kubernetes, docker-for-mac

When setting up an ingress in my kubernetes project I can't seem to get it to work. I already checked following questions:

- [Enable Ingress controller on Docker Desktop with WLS2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65193758/enable-ingress-controller-on-docker-desktop-with-wls2)
- [Docker Desktop + k8s plus https proxy multiple external ports to pods on http in deployment?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60839510/docker-desktop-k8s-plus-https-proxy-multiple-external-ports-to-pods-on-http-in)
- [How can I access nginx ingress on my local?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59255445/how-can-i-access-nginx-ingress-on-my-local)

But I can't get it to work. When testing the service via NodePort (http://kubernetes.docker.internal:30090/ or localhost:30090) it works without any problem, but when using http://kubernetes.docker.internal/ I get kubernetes.docker.internal didn’t send any data. ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

This is my yaml file:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: webapp
spec:
  minReadySeconds: 30
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: webapp
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: webapp
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: webapp
          image: gcr.io/google-samples/hello-app:2.0
          env:
            - name: "PORT"
              value: "3000"

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: webapp-service

spec:
  selector:
    app: webapp

  ports:
    - name: http
      port: 3000
      nodePort: 30090 # only for NotPort > 30,000

  type: NodePort #ClusterIP inside cluster

---

apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: webapp-ingress
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: webapp-service
      port:
        number: 3000
  rules:
    - host: kubernetes.docker.internal
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name:  webapp-service
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

I also used following command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v0.45.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

The output of  `kubectl get all -A` is as follows (indicating that the ingress controller is running):

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                            READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
default         pod/webapp-78d8b79b4f-7whzf                     1/1     Running     0          13m
ingress-nginx   pod/ingress-nginx-admission-create-gwhbq        0/1     Completed   0          11m
ingress-nginx   pod/ingress-nginx-admission-patch-bxv9v         0/1     Completed   1          11m
ingress-nginx   pod/ingress-nginx-controller-6f5454cbfb-s2w9p   1/1     Running     0          11m
kube-system     pod/coredns-f9fd979d6-6xbxs                     1/1     Running     0          19m
kube-system     pod/coredns-f9fd979d6-frrrv                     1/1     Running     0          19m
kube-system     pod/etcd-docker-desktop                         1/1     Running     0          18m
kube-system     pod/kube-apiserver-docker-desktop               1/1     Running     0          18m
kube-system     pod/kube-controller-manager-docker-desktop      1/1     Running     0          18m
kube-system     pod/kube-proxy-mfwlw                            1/1     Running     0          19m
kube-system     pod/kube-scheduler-docker-desktop               1/1     Running     0          18m
kube-system     pod/storage-provisioner                         1/1     Running     0          18m
kube-system     pod/vpnkit-controller                           1/1     Running     0          18m

NAMESPACE       NAME                                         TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                      AGE
default         service/kubernetes                           ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                      19m
default         service/webapp-service                       NodePort       10.111.167.112   <none>        3000:30090/TCP               13m
ingress-nginx   service/ingress-nginx-controller             LoadBalancer   10.106.21.69     localhost     80:32737/TCP,443:32675/TCP   11m
ingress-nginx   service/ingress-nginx-controller-admission   ClusterIP      10.105.208.234   <none>        443/TCP                      11m
kube-system     service/kube-dns                             ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP       19m

NAMESPACE     NAME                        DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   NODE SELECTOR            AGE
kube-system   daemonset.apps/kube-proxy   1         1         1       1            1           kubernetes.io/os=linux   19m

NAMESPACE       NAME                                       READY   UP-TO-DATE   AVAILABLE   AGE
default         deployment.apps/webapp                     1/1     1            1           13m
ingress-nginx   deployment.apps/ingress-nginx-controller   1/1     1            1           11m
kube-system     deployment.apps/coredns                    2/2     2            2           19m

NAMESPACE       NAME                                                  DESIRED   CURRENT   READY   AGE
default         replicaset.apps/webapp-78d8b79b4f                     1         1         1       13m
ingress-nginx   replicaset.apps/ingress-nginx-controller-6f5454cbfb   1         1         1       11m
kube-system     replicaset.apps/coredns-f9fd979d6                     2         2         2       19m

NAMESPACE       NAME                                       COMPLETIONS   DURATION   AGE
ingress-nginx   job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-create   1/1           1s         11m
ingress-nginx   job.batch/ingress-nginx-admission-patch    1/1           3s         11m
```

I already tried debugging, and when doing an exec to the nginx service:
`kubectl exec service/ingress-nginx-controller -n ingress-nginx -it -- sh`
I can do the following curl: `curl -H "host:kubernetes.docker.internal" localhost` and it returns the correct content. So to me this seems like my loadbalancer service is not used when opening http://kubernetes.docker.internal via the browser. I also tried using the same curl from my terminal but that had the same 'empty response' result.

Comment: Does this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65403620/minikube-and-ingress-nginx-does-not-have-port-80-open/65410490#65410490 answer your question?

Comment: No, because I am not using minikube, I am using docker desktop

Comment: Just try the configs, minikube has nothing to do with it

Comment: Any updates? Did you try it? Does it work?

Comment: It does seem to work now, only problem is that the certificate is wrong when I use eg. https://api-l.test.be/ (I added that pointing to 127.0.0.1 in my /etc/hosts)

Comment: What do you mean it's "wrong"? default nginx ingress ssl certifiacte is [self signed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) so it want be seen as valid by a browser.

Comment: Never mind: the host we chose had htst enabled, so it was blocked by our browser, I also noticed it wasn't running stable until I added 'kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx" ' to my annotations of the ingress

Comment: Great. Would you mind providing the answer (in answers section for better visibility) explainaing what you did for others that may have that same issue?

Answer (score 3):

I knew this is quite outdated thread, but i think my answer can help later visitors

**Answer**: You have to install ingress controller. For exam: ingress-nginx controller,

either using **helm**:

```
helm upgrade --install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx \
--repo https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx \
--namespace ingress-nginx --create-namespace
```

or **kubectl**:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.2.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

you can find addional info [here](https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/deploy/#quick-start)

don't forget to add defined host to `/etc/hosts` file. e.g

```
127.0.0.1 your.defined.host
```

then access defined host as usual